# flexmojos ignoring configuration?

Tags: maven, swc, flexmojos

I am trying to build out a SWC file from a Flex library, and no matter what I do, flexmojos (3.6.1) seems to build a "config.xml" file in the bin/classes folder that is empty, and uses that for configuration, completely ignoring everything I put into the plugin > configuration element. I've tried it running command line, through m2e, and through Jenkins and I get the same problem every time. I'm stuck and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Here is the build portion of my POM.

```
<sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src</sourceDirectory>
<directory>${basedir}/bin</directory>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.sonatype.flexmojos</groupId>
        <artifactId>flexmojos-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.1</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.adobe.flex</groupId>
                <artifactId>compiler</artifactId>
                <version>${flex.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <configuration>
            <computeDigest>false</computeDigest>
            <allowSourcePathOverlap>true</allowSourcePathOverlap>
            <debug>false</debug>
            <warnings>
                <no-constructor>false</no-constructor>
            </warnings>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was running an older compile-swc target. When I flipped over to the new target I was fine. the m2e Eclipse plugin did not provide me the choice to select the latest target in their build configuration settings.